# How to get resource allocation size in D3D11

Tags: directx-11

Basically trying to find an equivalent for d3d12 resource size query

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-getresourceallocationinfo

Need to determine the actual resource size on GPU.

Answer (score 1):

That information is not exposed directly for Direct3D 11. Historically this information has been abstracted in Direct3D/OpenGL, but knowing the actual resource size is required for an app to manage video memory as required by Direct3D 12/Vulkan.

The best you can do with Direct3D 11 is make an estimate. [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex) has a lot of code for computing 'raw' image sizes of Direct3D resources for the pixels, but it can't tell you about any specific hardware requirements (stride, mip packing, etc.) that might make it larger than that. In other words, the size of the raw pixels is a 'minimum bound' on the actual size.